# Is np.gradient the average of backward and forward slopes at the boundaries

Tags: python, numpy, gradient

I'm trying to understand the explanation of `np.gradient` [Here](http://%20https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.gradient.html):

> The gradient is computed using second order accurate central
>   differences in the interior points and either first or second order
>   accurate one-sides (forward or backwards) differences at the
>   boundaries. The returned gradient hence has the same shape as the
>   input array.

How do the forward and backwards slopes are used in `np.gradient`? Is it taken as the average?

Comment: The code for this function Python, which you can read.  Look at the code blocks using `edge_order`.  For order 1, it is just the slope derived from the 2 end values.  Order 2 uses 3 points.